# GCP Monitoring Alert Notification Channel (Web Hook) with Slack Webhook

Tags: google-cloud-platform, webhooks, google-cloud-monitoring

I'm trying to use Slack Incoming web hook in a GCP monitoring notification channel of type Web hook. The Slack web hook URL is working good and works without any authentication.

But there seems to be no action when testing this. Can't I use the GCP Monitoring notification Webhook to link it with Incoming Web hook of Slack? Did web hook in google cloud notification channels need to be protected with authentication or it can be without it?

Comment: Please provide more details on how you're doing this? Are you writing code or using the UI? One of the supported notification channels is Slack and so you should be able to implement this directly using the Slack type rather than a Webhook: https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/support/notification-options#slack

Comment: First I added a Slack notification channel, tested it (successfully). Second, I added a Webhook (app) to Slack and configured the Webhook notification channel on Cloud Monitoring. It's interesting how limited the configuration is (so I'm probably missing something). When I test the Webhook, it (not surprisingly) fails. Cloud Monitoring reports that it sent the notification successfully but the Webhook wasn't triggered on Slack. I would expect (!?) some mechanism by which Cloud Monitoring would permit configuring the Webhook message. The Slack channel works. I recommend you use that.

Comment: I think the Webhook schema is incompatible with what Slack expects: https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/support/notification-options#webhooks